# How to operate with arrays;Bissection

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Been trying to get why I get that The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()and a work around

My code is:

```
def y(T):
    y= Eatm + (1-alfa)*Esolar_interpolado-sigma*T*4-beta*(T-Tar_interpolado)
    return y

def bissec(y,xLow,xHigh,maxErro,maxIter):
    nIter=0
    if np.any(y(xLow)*y(xHigh)>0):
        raiz=float('nan')  # not a number: ERRO
    else:
        erroAbs=xHigh-xLow
        while erroAbs>maxErro and nIter<maxIter:
            nIter=nIter+1
            raiz=0.5*(xHigh+xLow)
            if y(xLow)*y(raiz)<0:
                xHigh=raiz
            elif y(xLow)*y(raiz)>0:
                    xLow=raiz
            else:
                xHigh=raiz
                xLow=raiz
                erroAbs=xHigh-xLow
        return raiz,erroAbs,nIter
```

error message:

```
bissec(y,1,500,0.0001,100)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-49-2bb9b9f27835>", line 1, in <module>
    bissec(y,1,500,0.0001,100)

  File "<ipython-input-37-b19accf5aa25>", line 10, in bissec
    if y(xLow)*y(raiz)<0:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I do think the problem is the bissection method was meant for fixed constants but in this case constants change by hour per day per month per year so each constant is an array and I think that's what's causing the error.

Last resort I will make for loop that does a lines for each constant values so around 350000 lines in the plot

Comment: `array>.1` produces a boolean array the same size as `array`.  A boolean array with more than one value cannot be used an `if` expression.  Hance ambiguity error.  Look at all values in the 'error' expression.

Comment: I'm guessing there is some problem with the `while True` loop. It lacks `break`, so there is no way to exit it.

Comment: I really can't check individually it has over 350000values

Comment: Please clarify your question. Maybe include the full error message.

Comment: Could you provide some minimal input / (expected) output?

Comment: It's still hard to understand your problem. Why line 10 and 12 have different condition than line 3?

Comment: @rpoleski its the bissection method,ps: `return` works as `break` and i use it as it spares me one line

Comment: @norok2 the **input** is kind of guessing **output** a root of the function

Comment: It would be easier to help you if all information needed to reproduce it was provided. I've added values of some constants and your code (current version) runs without an error.